# How to play a video in launch screen in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, launch-screen

I literally been searching this for two months & cant find answer . Everyone talks about splash screen but my app needs a video play in launch screen in swiftUI native app.

Answer (score -1):

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Your_videoFile_name", withExtension: "mp4")!)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .onAppear {
                    player.play()
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add some information on how this addresses the question.